# Change data inside select element but leave the one selected

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help mi with solving this problem. I would like to change data inside select element but don't change the option that is selected at the time. I am using ajax to get data into element.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Save the value of the select before you change the contents, then reassign the value after.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I tried it and it is not working, I have multiple elements that I would like to be able to change each other data. So when I Have element 1 selected It loads data to element 2 but when I will change element 2 it clears element 1. I tried do what You are talking about, I can see that for 1 second the selected element in 1 is changed but then it's clear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.